# Best choice of word to say "a problem exists"

Tags: word-choice

I am wondering if one can use the verb "exist" for a problem; particularly to say
"the speaker will explain the problem exists in social media"

More generally, I tend to think that exist should not be used with negative concepts such as "complication" or "ambiguity" or "problem".

What is the best choice of words for either concepts?

Comment: Problems exist.  Ambiguities exist.  Complications exist.  What's the problem?  Opportunities exist.  Choices and options exist.  The verb can be used where it's convenient to use it.

Comment: @Xanne. I agree but also remember being reprimanded by an English professor (at uni) for using **exist** as a verb at all ... regardless of what the word was being applied to. I thought he was wrong, but wasn't really in a position to argue with him.

Comment: @SteveLovell -- Hard to believe that someone could argue that "exist" is not a verb.

Comment: @Lawrence, it's nearly 20 years ago now, but the context was a paper I'd prepared discussing an argument for the existence of God. The sentence would have been something like _Therefore, God exists._ But this really isn't the place for such a discussion.

Comment: @SteveLovell I see. That's quite a different thing, then. I'll delete my previous comment.

Comment: I can see several reasons to be wary of 'exists', but as a point of language itself I don't think you have anything to worry about. "Exists" is perfectly acceptable is such cases. The problems come only when you try to read off the 'real structure' of the world from the structure and content of our (true) utterances. I would say however that your first quoted sentence doesn't seem well formed, but it's hard to correct it without further context explaining what you're trying to say.

Comment: "Houston, we've got a problem."

Comment: This is very confusing; the parse is unclear. I think it's because you've either omitted important connective words you should not have left out or else because you have inserted words you should not have put in. Do you mean that  ❶ *“The speaker will explain **THAT** the problem exists in social media”*, or do you mean that  ❷  *“The speaker will explain the problem **WHICH** exists in social media”*, or do you mean that  ❸  *”The speaker will explain the problem **IN/OF** social media”*?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any resources about the use of "exist" with positive concepts. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exist) provides some definitions for the word, among them are definitions which are negative in nature.

> ***exist***: to have being in a specified place or with respect to
>   understood limitations or conditions

or

> ***exist***: to live at an inferior level or under adverse circumstances

The use of "exist" along with "problem" is very common. Just looking at a bunch of examples of Merriam-Webster, and I found one:

> We shouldn't ignore the *problems* that *exist* in our own community.

Answer (score 0):

More apt would be

> The speaker will ***demonstrate this anomaly*** in social media.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem. Informally, it is fine to say that a problem *exists*. But, in a formal text, it just doesn't sound entirely...felicitous.

A problem can **be** such and such. One can **have** or **experience** a problem. A problem can **remain** such and such. A problem can **arise**. Perhaps there are other common options.

If none of those fit the sentence, it's often better to recast it.